# Fragment Manager compiling error when adding a PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, preferencefragment

I have one Activity where I put all my fragments in. I now want to add a PreferenceFragment instead of a normal Fragment. I am using the non-support version of the Fragment Manager for this.

During compilation, I get this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app_identifier/app_identifier.ActMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
```

I'm selecting the fragments through a Navigation Drawer, so I have a switch statement to select the fragments. Here is how it looks, cut to the important parts:

```
private void displaySelectedScreen(int id) {
        android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        PreferenceFragment preferenceFragment = null;

        int fragment_type;

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_compare: {
                fragment = new Fragment_Compare();
                fragment_type = 0;
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_settings: {
                preferenceFragment = new Fragment_Settings();
                fragment_type = 1;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                fragment = new Fragment_Compare();
                fragment_type = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        switch (fragment_type) {
            case 0: {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_act_compare, fragment).commit();
            }
            case 1: {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_act_compare, preferenceFragment).commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

The compiler crashes in `case 1`.

The normal Fragment Classes extend the normal `android.app.Fragment` class and the Settings class extends `android.preference.PreferenceFragment`

I have tried using the support v4 library, but I firstly don't need that, and it also didn't work. I'm guessing I have to call the transaction differently, but I couldn't find out how.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** The code of my Fragment_Settings class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment_Settings extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.nav_item_settings);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured that the `replace()` method only takes a normal Fragment class, is there a Manager or function which takes PreferenceFragment's?

Comment: The error you listed is a Runtime error, not a compilation one. Which steps are you taking that lead to this? Are you sure the error occurs in the case statement?

Comment: `mFragmentManager` might be null. Show us more code, specially where `mFragmentManager` is present.

Comment: Yes I am sure, when I comment the line out, it doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: I don't have a `mFragmentManager` anywhere in my code, but I edited to post and added the code of my settings class

Comment: You must have `mFragmentManager` somewhere - the error shows that performing method on it causes `NullPointerException`

Comment: I don't, searched through the entire project. It's probably an intern method of the FragmentManager, because it only takes a normal Fragment as paramater, it's probably causing the error because I give in a PreferenceFragment. But I don't know how I should give it in otherwise.

Comment: Alright, apparently I just had to remove the `onCreateView` method from my Settings class and just cast it into a normal fragment object, which previously gave me an error.